# How to attribute dynamic values for table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, 1 with prices, another with customers and the last with dependents of customers like a health insurance. When I have 1 customer and 1 dependent the value for the first dependent is one, when I have two dependents the value of second dependent is different, but the first is the same.

I need a query that shows the dependents table and gets the value of each dependent, 4 dependents are the maximum.

Dependent Table

```
+--------------+--------+---------+------------+
| id_dependent |  name  | number  | primary_id |
+--------------+--------+---------+------------+
|           51 | Carlos |  956585 |          2 |
|           52 | João   |  985868 |          2 |
|           53 | Jaime  |  985868 |          2 |
|           54 | Evan   |  985847 |          3 |
|           55 | Kaus   |  584788 |          3 |
+--------------+--------+---------+------------+
```

Price Table

```
+----------+---------+-----------+-------+---------+
| price_id | Product | Dependent | Value | Plan_id |
+----------+---------+-----------+-------+---------+
|       11 | Plan1   |         1 | 15,00 |      56 |
|       12 | Plan1   |         2 | 13,50 |      56 |
|       13 | Plan1   |         3 | 11,50 |      56 |
+----------+---------+-----------+-------+---------+
```

What I need

```
+--------------+--------+--------+------------+-------+
| id_dependent |  name  | number | primary_id | Value |
+--------------+--------+--------+------------+-------+
|           51 | Carlos | 956585 |          2 | 15,00 |
|           52 | João   | 985868 |          2 | 13,50 |
|           53 | Jaime  | 985868 |          2 | 11,50 |
|           54 | Evan   | 985847 |          3 | 15,00 |
|           55 | Kaus   | 584788 |          3 | 13,50 |
+--------------+--------+--------+------------+-------+
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the dependents and then `join`:

```
select d.*, p.price
from (select d.*, row_number() over (partition by primary_id order by id_dependent) as seqnum
      from dependents d
     ) d left join
     price p
     on p.dependent = d.seqnum and p.plan_id = 56;
```

In earlier versions of MySQL, you can use variables:

```
select d.*, p.price
from (select d.*,
             (@rn := if(@p = d.primary_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@p := d.primary_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from (select d.* from dependents d order by primary_id, id_dependent) d cross join
           (select @p := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) d left join
     price p
     on p.dependent = d.seqnum and p.plan_id = 56;
```

Notes on the use of variables:

- They are deprecated and may be removed in future versions of MySQL.
- The `order by` is in a subquery; that is needed in some versions of MySQL.  Variables and `order by` don't always play well together.
- Both variables are assigned in the same expression.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions, so this is very important for working code.

Comment: I think my server version is out dated can u have some suggestion to emulate `row_number`?

Answer (score 0):

This works with mysql 5.6 and 5.7

```
Select d.`id_dependent`, d.`name`, d.`number`, d.`primary_id`, p.`Value`
From (
  SELECT   d.*,
      if (@primid = primary_id,@curRank := @curRank + 1,@curRank := 1) AS rank,
      @primid := primary_id 
  FROM Dependent d, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r , (SELECT @primid := 0) s
  ORDER BY  primary_id,id_dependent) d 
 left join price p on p.Dependent = d.rank
 Order by d.`id_dependent`;
```

Which results in

```
id_dependent    name    number  primary_id  Value
51              Carlos  956585  2           15,00
52              João    985868  2           13,50
53              Jaime   985868  2           11,50
54              Evan    985847  3           15,00
55              Kaus    584788  3           13,50
```